# swift Is there a way I can change screens with a navigation controller

Tags: swift

I have a flow wherever (for the first time), I have to enter screen A and from there on I need to move to screen B.

Home(App) --> A --> B (First time)
Home(App) --> B

I have a navigation controller in A that guides us to A and B(first time) and B the second time.
I'm done with done the latter case of
Home(App) --> B

Any ideas for doing case 1 ?
My main question there is a button in A to set the options. Should I use the navigation controller or not?

Comment: Personally, I’m not really clear on what the question is asking. But you can think of a navigation controller as a way to keep a stack of view controllers. You can push and pop view controllers off of that stack. If that fits your use case, go for it

Comment: use ``NSUserDefaults`` to save a simple variable to check if its the first launch or not? Set your rootView to B and then check the value of this ``NSUserDefault`` saved value, if its first launch, push view A without animation. If not , do nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are saying that for your very first launch you want to first display screen A, then screen B.

In all subsequent launches you want to go directly to screen B, and never need screen A again.

Then you say "Any ideas for doing case 1 ? My main question there is a button in A to set the options. Should I use the navigation controller or not?"

What is case 1? Are you saying you might need to revisit screen A to set options?

You could make screen A your root view controller, and display it on first launch. On subsequent launches you could push screen B on top of screen A without animation. If the user needs to set options, you could pop screen B and reveal screen A.

I guess, alternately, you could make screen B your root view controller. On first launch, push screen A on top of Screen B. When the user dismisses it, you go back to screen B. On subsequent launches, just display screen B and skip screen A. If the user needs to set options, create and push an options screen on top of the current screen.

(note that I'm using your term "screen", but should really be using the term view controller instead.)